# How do I force-enclose a CodeModel expression in brackets?

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I want to generate some very common code using Sun's CodeModel

```
while ((sbt = reader.readLine()) != null)
{

}
```

However when I write:

```
JWhileLoop whileJsonBuilder = block._while(JExpr
                            .ref("partJsonString").assign(JExpr.ref("reader"))
                            .ne(JExpr._null()));
```

I get

```
while (partJsonString = reader!= null) {
    stringBuilder.append(partJsonString);
}
```

Notice that the brackets are missing.
How can I force brackets to appear in the code?

Comment: `for (;;) { String sbt = reader.readLine(); if (sbt == null) break; ... }` is feasible in CodeModel. There is no reason to prefer that while pattern as being better style, contrary.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But I was thinking that there would be a way to achieve while in codeModel, afterall it is written by Sun.

Comment: There seems to be only a subset of assign statements for instance. I sought quickly after comma-expression too - to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to find a preexisting way to add parenthesis.  You can, however, extend JCodeModel to handle this by adding a special JExpression to render the paraenthesis:

```
public class ParensExpession extends JExpressionImpl{

    private JExpression expression;

    public ParensExpession(JExpression expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    @Override
    public void generate(JFormatter formatter) {
        formatter.p('(').g(expression).p(')');
    }
}
```

Incorporated into your code:

```
JWhileLoop whileJsonBuilder = block._while(
    new ParensExpession(
        JExpr.ref("partJsonString").assign(JExpr.ref("reader"))
    ).ne(JExpr._null()));
```

Gives:

```
while ((partJsonString = reader)!= null);
```